# I need to navigate from one page to an another page on xamarin.Forms.app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Because I'm new to Xamarin, I really have no idea how to switch between pages. so I refer to internet and found some solution. But there are some errors.Can anyone help to sort out this issue? Here's my code in app.cs file.I put comments to the codes that I'm not sure. When I click the btn1, that triggered an error called "pushAsync is not supported globally on iOS".

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace mine
{
    public class App : Application
    {
    public App ()
        {

            // The root page of your application


            Button btn1 = new Button();
            Button btn2 = new Button();
            Button btn3 = new Button();
            btn1.Text= "Farmer";
            btn2.Text= "Advisor";
            btn3.Text= "Supplier";

            MainPage = new ContentPage {
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Rice Growing Advisor!"
                                //App.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyCustomContentPage());
                                //App.Navigation.PushAsync (new MainPage ());
                        }, btn1,btn2,btn3
                    }
                }

            

            };
            //var np = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            //MainPage=np;
            //MainPage = new NavigationPage (MainPage);
            //var rootPage = new NavigationPage(MainPage);



            btn1.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
                //MainPage= new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
                //MainPage = np;

                await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage());
                MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(MainPage);
                
                


            };

        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to first set your Mainpage as Navigation page and then you push a page on it.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight he has written the error as a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation is property of a VisualElement. All code for Button.Clicked is in constructor of App class(which is subcalass of Application), which has no "Navigation" property.
In your case you can use MainPage.Navigation(because MainPage is a Page and Page is a VisualElement). But there is one more problem: your MainPage is not NavigationPage, so you cannot perform PushAsync(..). TO  fix this problem you should just wrap ContentPage into Navigation Page like this:

```
    var page = new ContentPage {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children = {
                new Label {
                    XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                    Text = "Welcome to Rice Growing Advisor!"
                        //App.Navigation.PushAsync(new MyCustomContentPage());
                        //App.Navigation.PushAsync (new MainPage ());
                }, btn1,btn2,btn3
            }
        }
    };

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);
```

Btw, [this arcticle](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/) will help u to understand what is going on.

**EDIT :**

```
using System;   
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace test 
{ 
    public class App : Application 
    { 
        public App () 
        {
            // The root page of your application

            // set up properties via object initializer for clarity
            Button btn1 = new Button {Text = "Farmer"};
            Button btn2 = new Button {Text = "Advisor"};
            Button btn3 = new Button {Text = "Supplier"};

            var page = new ContentPage {
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            // XAlign is obsolete, use HorizontalTextAlignment instead
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Rice Growing Advisor!"
                        }, btn1,btn2,btn3
                    }
                }
            };

            // wrap our page into NavigationPage
            // if we dont do that, we'll get "PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS" exception
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);

            btn1.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
                var secondPage = new ContentPage
                {
                    Content = new Label
                    {
                        Text = "Click \"BACK\" to navigate backward", 
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
                    }
                };
                secondPage.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("BACK", null, async () => { await secondPage.Navigation.PopAsync();}));

                await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(secondPage);
            };
        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this works properly.

Comment: Hey @flame239, Thank you very much for your answer.I just did the way you describe here and there's a error in my main.cs file only when clicked the button. I can put the error here."System.InvalidOperationException has being thrown. NavigationPage must have a root page before being used". so can I know how to set my mainpage as the rootpage and where to put that code? other thing there's an another error in the main.cs file when I click the button. It's Saying pushAsync is not supported globally on ios. please use a navigation page. so what I wanna do? Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: @ISURU show me, please, your current code, because code in your post contains a lot of other errors(for example, "new ExamplePage()" satement is invalid, ExamplePage has no constructor without arguments; "new ExamplePage(stackIndex + 1)" - stackIndex is not defined; "Navigation.RemovePage(this)" - argument should be of type Page, not Application;and so on...)

Comment: hey @flame239 the code i wrote for the button click was as follows.
btn1.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {                            await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage());     MainPage.Navigation.RemovePage(MainPage);

};
I delete all the other codes that I have been insert. This is the only code  I wrote new. but when I click the button there was an error as “pushAsync is not supported globally on ios”.I'm pretty sure you won't get a clear idea by this comment. really Im full of this, I tried the whole day, but I was not able to make it.. :(

Comment: @ISURU there is no point in dicussing this by email. we have this wonderful site, where everybody can offer a good solution. I assume, your project is not so big, so just create new question(or edit this) and insert the whole project code there.
P.S> I dont understand why this question was put on hold.

Comment: ok sure m8, I'll edit the code in my question. I think admins put this thread under hold because they mention this seems to be not a question. and they said, I should mention the errors. but I've already mention them as comments. anyway I'll edit the code as my current code. Thank you flame. :)

Comment: @ISURU edited my post

Comment: Hey @flame. Your code works perfectly. Thank you very much for your support. Cheers!!! xD

Answer (score 0):

`Navigation` is a property of Page. You have to call something like

```
await MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ExamplePage(1));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Sven-Michael Stübe. Got it!! :)